# Azure SQL database with MFA login to connect from Azure ADF

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have an Azure SQL server and database which have MFA login and I am the admin. But when I try to establish a connection via a new linked service from ADF to this database using System Managed Identity option, it throws error -
"Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: 'Server details', Database: 'database name', User: ''. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.

[image]
[image]
I have already given contributor role access to ADF in SQL database using system managed Identity. Also, I have tried to access this database using Autoresolve runtime and azure runtime. But still the error is coming.

Comment: Did you add SQL database firewall rule with the client IP address. Refer this Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql#manage-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal)

Comment: I added this already but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created Azure SQL database in portal and created linked service in azure data factory with managed identity authentication I got below error:

[image]

I followed below procedure to resolve this:
I turned on the managed identity of data factory

[image]

I set admin for azure SQL database:

[image]

Login with Admin to sql database Create User username as data factory name using below code:

```
CREATE USER [DATAFACTORY NAME] FROM eXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

[image]

Added rules to the user using below code:

```
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [DATA FACTORY NAME];
```

[image]

I tested linked service again, tested successfully

[image]

It worked for me, once check from your end.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed process...it worked for me once I followed these steps!

Comment: Worked for me. Does not seem to be mentioned in any Azure documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are missing the user creation and role assignment within the SQL database:

Connect to the database with your account and create an account for the data factory:

```sql
CREATE USER [<datafactory-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Then grant it the required role for your task:

```sql
ALTER ROLE [<roleName>] ADD MEMBER [<datafactory-name>]
```

Some available role names are:

- db_accessadmin
- db_backupoperator
- db_datareader
- db_datawriter
- db_ddladmin
- db_denydatareader
- db_denydatawriter
- db_owner
- db_securityadmin
- public

Comment: Created the user as well with the name of the azure data factory and granted permissions even. Still the same issue.

Comment: On Managed Instance, you must create a login before creating the user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current&preserve-view=true